# Le « meuble meublant » et l'étoffe « meublante » : emploi usuel, fréquence, saisons ?

Tags: vocabulaire, droit-et-justice

[image]
[image]

<sup>[ [*Les établissements de Saint Louis*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54073806/f131.image), (13<sup>e</sup> s.)  / [*Dictionnaire universel, contenant généralement tous les mots françois tant vieux que modernes & les termes des sciences et des arts*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5542578m/f918.image), Tome 2, Antoine Furetière, Seconde édition (1690), *meuble* (extrait) ]</sup>

---

On nous dit que *meublant* pour *apte à [meubler](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/meubler)* (1835, [Ac.6](http://artflsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/dicos/pubdico1look.pl?strippedhw=meublant)) est « vieilli, sauf dans la [langue juridique](http://www.dictionnaire-juridique.com/definition/meuble.php) » ([Ac.9](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/meublant)). Larousse ne le marque ni [vieilli](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/meublant_meublante/51051), ni ne réserve [*meuble meublant*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/meublant_meublante/51051/locution) au domaine juridique ; le TLFi note l'emploi en droit pour *meuble meublant* mais ne marque pas *meublant* vieilli. Larousse simplifie les sens de [*meubler*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/meubler/51057?q=meubler#50949) en deux sens utiles ici, soit « garnir un local de meubles », ou « être propre à garnir, à décorer un lieu ».

> *Il est dur de payer très-cher, comme excellents
>  De tout petits
>   tableaux qui ne sont pas meublants* (Augier) [apte à meubler]
>
> *Un goût plutôt capricieux (...) a gorgé les murs de chromos (...),
>   paré, pomponné les meubles meublants, deux fauteuils et quatre
>   chaises, de housses...* (Verlaine) [droit]
>
> [ Trésor de la langue française informatisé, *TLFi*, [*meublant*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/meublant) ]

---

- *Meuble(s) meublant(s)* a-t-il un sens usuel (non technique) aujourd'hui, et si oui, lequel (on pense à quels meubles) ; est-il devenu usuel de connaître ce [terme](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCode.do;jsessionid=607FED2C50388458379FF41F9BDD1175.tpdila09v_3?idSectionTA=LEGISCTA000006136242&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070721&dateTexte=20161103#LEGIARTI000006428753) technique, de l'employer, ou est-ce compris comme un pléonasme ?
- *Meublant* en adjectif pour « apte à meubler » (le fameux exemple de 1835 ds. Ac.6 : *étoffe bien meublante*) est-il vieilli ou complètement (en 180 ans) sorti d'usage ?
- Incidemment, que sont ces *meubles d'été/d'hiver* chez Furetière ; que serait-ce qu'un *meuble meublant d'hiver*, si ça existe ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le sens du verbe "meubler" a évolué au cours du temps. Il est passé de "rendre habitable" à "remplir un espace vide":

> Je mets de la musique pour meubler le silence de ma maison.
>
> Je ne veux pas d'une couleur unie pour mes murs. Il me faut un motif plus meublant, comme des rayures.

L'expression "les meubles meublants" (ou juste "les meublants") est encore utilisée aujourd'hui avec le même sens, mais seulement dans le domaine juridique. Dans le discours courant on dit plutôt "meubles utilitaires" car "meublant" serait compris comme "accessoire inutile destiné à remplir un espace vide", ce qui serait un contresens.

Les meubles d'été et d'hiver se rapportent au fait que par le passé les plus riches disposaient de plusieurs jeux de meubles qui alternaient selon la saison. On avait donc certains meubles destinés à l'été, et d'autres à l'hiver.

Comment: un meuble utilitaire est un meuble qui a une utilité. Par exemple une baignoire sert à prendre des bains, un fourneau sert à se réchauffer ou à y faire cuire des aliments. En revanche un tableau ou une plante en pot ne sont pas utilitaires car ils ne servent qu'à la décoration.

Comment: Merci. Si je comprends bien une chaise et une causeuse seraient des meubles utilitaires ?

Comment: c'est cela, en effet.